# Evolute hypersurfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, contact-geometry

Do you have any references on studies examining the evolute (or focal) hypersurface to a given hypersurface in dimension greater than 3 ?

The evolute can for instance be defined as the envelope of normal lines to the hypersurface.